# Installation difficulty; Cannot add apportable sdk bin directory into path

Tags: apportable

I am attempting to install Apportable, and I am currently attempting to add the apportable sdk bin directory into the path.  Like the sample app instruction video says, I copy and paste this: "(echo; echo 'PATH="/Users/testuser/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH"') >> ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bash_profile" into terminal, but I keep getting this error message: "-bash: "/Users/testuser/.bash_profile: Permission denied"

I am not sure how to proceed, or what I'm doing wrong.  Any advice that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you don't have write permission to your own .bash_profile.

Here's something to try -

## save the original .bash_profile

```
cp /Users/testuser/.bash_profile /Users/testuser/.bash_profile-save
```

## change the permissions

```
chmod +w .bash_profile
```

## update the path

```
(echo; echo 'PATH="/Users/testuser/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH"') >> ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bash_profile
```